# Is there an earlier version of "Our Exploits at West Poley" (1985)?

Tags: alternate-version, our-exploits-at-west-poley

I recently watched the British kids' film "Our Exploits at West Poley". This version was made in 1985 and is the only one that I have found referred to online.

However, I distinctly remember watching this film (or another based on the same book) as a boy way back in 1956/7. Does anyone have info on this? Was it made under another title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This article](http://www.thomashardyfilms.com/lost_hardy_adaptations.htm) indicates that you are right:

> **The Secret Cave**
>
> Production Companies: Merton Park Studios, Ltd.; Children’s Film Foundation (UK).  Distributor:  Associated British Films.  Director: John Durst.  Producer: Frank Hoare.  Screenplay: Joe Mendoza, ***based on Hardy’s novella “Our Exploits at West Poley.”*** Cinematography: Martin Curtis. Length: 62 minutes.  Premiere: **1953**.

> NOTES:
>
> Like Under the Greenwood Tree, The Secret Cave may not actually be lost; however, information on the film's availability is scarce.  A children's film, The Secret Cave has the distinction of being the only English-language motion picture based on a Hardy source between 1929's Under the Greenwood Tree and 1967's Far from the Madding Crowd.
> ... The same story would be filmed again in 1985 under the name of the source material, Our Exploits at West Poley.

Subsequently typing *"the secret cave" 1953* brings up a lot of links for the film, including the following:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169213/

https://www2.bfi.org.uk/films-tv-people/4ce2b6aa31788

https://www.avclub.com/film/reviews/the-secret-cave-1953

https://letterboxd.com/film/the-secret-cave/

https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/322965-the-secret-cave?language=en-US

[image]

NB.

If anyone remembers the popular childrens show "Animal Magic", this was presenter Johnny Morris's first film role.